# Conditional fields in Liferay Web Content editor

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

We have a requirement for creating a banner for which we plan to use *Web Content Display*.

As part of the implementation I have created a structure with the required fields like link-type (drop-down), etc and using corresponding template.

I wish to make a conditional check based on the type of selection in the link-type and show `link-to-page` or `text-box`.

I observed that there is no option to have a conditional check in the article editor rendering.

Thus I wish to check whether there is any hack or trick that we can do to achieve the above conditional thing? 
Also, can we inject custom Javascript to achieve this as part of the structure?

Comment: You will have to create a custom field type, which is described in the [WIKI](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Dynamic+Data+Mapping+-+Field+Types+Customization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have to stick to the default options in the liferay structure. I plan to use **separator** provided by LR to categories the elements to avoid end user (admin) confusion.

P.S. I was not able to locate any cool doc that would help in implementing the suggestion made by @Tobias (sorry, but I guess the wiki link above assumes you to be an expert of LR, and even the sample links in there does not work).